# Data binding associations in ExtJS admin template

Tags: extjs, associations

I'm unsuccessful in getting binding associations working in the admin dashboard template (with the desired behavior of selecting a record from a combobox and pulling up associated records in a grid).

My main viewModel is defined as:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main',


    stores: {
        patients: {
            model: 'md_registry.model.Patient', 
            autoLoad: true
        }
    }

});
```

I added a leaf node to Pages in NavigationTree.js:

```
{
            text: 'Pages',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-leanpub',
            expanded: false,
            selectable: false,
            //routeId: 'pages-parent',
            //id: 'pages-parent',

            children: [

                {
                    text: 'Proc',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-send',
                    rowCls: 'nav-tree-badge nav-tree-badge-hot',
                    viewType: 'procedure',
                    leaf: true
                }]
}
```

With the procedure view being:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.pages.Procedure', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'procedure',

    requires: [
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Admin.model.Patient',
        'Admin.model.Procedure'
        //'Admin.model.Diagnosis'
    ],

    anchor : '100% -1',

    referenceHolder: true,


    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    referenceHolder: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },


    viewModel: 'main',
    session: {},

    items: [
        // https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299301-Bind-combobox-displayField-value-to-displayfield

        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            layout: 'anchor',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                listeners : {
                    select : function() {
                        console.log(arguments)
                        console.log(arguments[1].data.birth_date)
                        console.log(arguments[1].data.first_name)
                        console.log(arguments[1].data.last_name)
                        console.log(arguments[1].data.sex)

                    }
                },
                bind: {
                    store: '{patients}'
                },
                reference: 'patientCombo',
                publishes: 'id',
                fieldLabel: 'Patient Search',
                displayField: 'mrn',
                //anchor: '-',
                // We're forcing the query to run every time by setting minChars to 0
                // (default is 4)
                minChars: 2,
                queryParam: '0',
                queryMode: 'local',
                typeAhead: true,
                // https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?156505-Local-combobox-with-any-match-filter
                doQuery: function(queryString, forceAll) {
                    this.expand();
                    this.store.clearFilter(!forceAll);

                    if (!forceAll) {
                        this.store.filter(this.displayField, new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(queryString), 'i'));
                    }
                }


            }, {
                // https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299301-Bind-combobox-displayField-value-to-displayfield
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Selected Patient',
                bind: {
                    html: '<p>Name: <b>{patientCombo.selection.first_name}, ' +
                    '{patientCombo.selection.last_name} </b></p>' +
                    '<p>Sex: {patientCombo.selection.sex}</p>' +
                    '<p>Birthdate: {patientCombo.selection.birth_date}</p>'
                }


            }]
        },


        {
            title: 'Procedures',
            xtype: 'grid',
            bind: '{patientCombo.selection.procedures}',
            flex: 1,
            margin: '0 0 0 10',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Procedure Date', dataIndex: 'proc_date', flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Procedure', dataIndex: 'proc_name', flex: 1
            }],

            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowexpander',
                rowBodyTpl : new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<p><b>Proc Name Orig:</b> {proc_name_orig}</p>',
                    '<p><b>Proc Code:</b> {proc_code}</p>',
                    '<p><b>Proc Code Type:</b> {proc_code_type}</p>')
            }],

            viewConfig: {
                emptyText: 'No procedures',
                deferEmptyText: false
            }
        }]
});
```

My Patient and Procedure models are simply:

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Procedure', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        //{ name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_code', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_code_type', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_name_orig', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_date', type: 'date', format: 'Y-m-d' },
        {
            name: 'patient_id',
            type: 'string',
            reference: {
                parent: 'Admin.model.Patient',
                //type: 'md_registry.model.Patient',
                inverse: 'procedures',
                autoLoad: false
            }
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/procedureview/api/read',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }

});
```

and

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Patient', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
    ],

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'mrn', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'birth_date', type: 'date', format: 'Y-m-d' },
        { name: 'sex', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'first_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'last_name', type: 'string' }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/patientview/api/read',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ''
        }
    }

});
```

respectively.

The data for my Patients store are getting loaded into the combobox just fine, but when I select an item from the combo list it is not firing off the call to grab the associated procedures data (see image: [image: of no binding association].

However, the binding associations work as expected with Side Navigation Tabs (see image: [image: of working binding association], and show up within the object prototype chain, as expected... see

[image: associations bound to model]

(whereas for the admin dashboard, the associations are empty).

I cannot for the life of me get these working in the Admin Dashboard. I noticed a tool called the bind inspector, but I am running the GPL version of the SDK, so I do not have access to this. Beyond this, I cannot figure out a way to debug why the binding association is not working in the admin dashboard, but otherwise works perfectly well in Side Navigation Tabs.

I would set up a Fiddle, but I have no idea how to do it using the Admin Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. It was a namespace issue.

My reference in the procedure model should be:

```
reference: {
                parent: 'Patient',
                inverse: 'procedures',
                autoLoad: false
            }
```

Voila, all the associated data get loaded as expected!